# Growth of Functions

Tags: computational-complexity

Does there exist a function f s.t.:

(1) $f(f(n)) \in O(f(n))$

(2) $f(n) \in \Omega(\cup_i n^i)$

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is no. By (1), we know that $f(f(n))\leq k f(n)$ for some constant $k$ and sufficiently large $n$. By (2), we get in particular that $c n^2\leq f(n)$ for some constant $c$ and sufficiently large $n$. This implies that $f(n)$ eventually gets large, and so applying it again we get $c (f(n))^2\leq f(f(n))$ for sufficiently large $n$, which implies $c f(n)^2\leq k f(n)$ for sufficiently large $n$, and so $c f(n)\leq k$, which implies $f$ is bounded, contrary to (2).

Comment: Sorry.  This answer is too elegant, too simple, and too correct;  try again.  If you don't lower the bar for the rest of us on MathOverflow Joel, how do you expect us to keep up?  Gerhard "Wish I Thought Of It" Paseman, 2011.03.08

Comment: Then again, you didn't generalize it to weakening 2) to \Omega(n*g(n)), where g(n) is some slowly increasing non-bounded function, so I guess we can let this answer pass.  Gerhard "But On The Other Hand" Paseman, 2011.03.08

Comment: Gerhard, you flatter me! 